# MIKROTIK - Join 2 different IP networks

Tags: local-area-network, mikrotik

Scenario:

I have 1 ISP.
The Mikrotik router is connected to that ISP in ether1 (192.168.0.3).
Mikrotik gives out DHCP addresses 10.0.0.0/8. My PC is connected to it (10.0.0.6).
The other network has a router(ddwrt) that connects to the mikrotik router and gives out 10.1.1.1/8 addresses

I want network 10.0.0.x to be able to connect with network 10.1.1.x, specifically my PC to monitor other computers on the other network.
How can I proceed of this? Thank you so much!

[image: image scenario]

Answer (score 1):

Adding a static route on the mikrotik router should be enough (https://wiki.mikrotik.com/wiki/Simple_Static_Routes_Example)

```
/ip route add dst-address=10.1.1.0/24 gateway=10.0.0.7
```

Comment: Thank you for your input. However, I still cannot reach the other router (10.1.1.1) or the other PCs via ping. Ive included /ip export for your reference: 

https://pastebin.com/aJDTp3wx

Comment: You have the IP address 10.1.1.1/8 configured on your Mikrotik: `/ip address add address=10.1.1.1/8 interface=bridge1 network=10.0.0.0`. Also, you cannot use a 10.0.0.0/8 subnet on both the Mikrotik and DD-WRT networks, as the two subnets are guaranteed to conflict. You would need to change them both to something no bigger than a /16. This answer is 100% correct.